# Right parameters for strip_unused_nodes

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Tensorflow Graph Transforms page https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/README.md shows how to use `strip_unused_nodes`.
But how to know the right values of X and Y in `strip_unused_nodes(type=X, shape="y0,y1,y3,3")` for my model?

Output of `summarize_graph` on my MobileNetV2 model :

```
Found 1 possible inputs: (name=image_tensor, type=uint8(4), shape=[?,?,?,3]) 
No variables spotted.
Found 4 possible outputs: (name=detection_boxes, op=Identity) (name=detection_scores, op=Identity) (name=detection_classes, op=Identity) (name=num_detections, op=Identity) 
Found 3457096 (3.46M) const parameters, 0 (0) variable parameters, and 623 control_edges
Op types used: 1707 Const, 525 Identity, 277 Mul, 194 Add, 170 Reshape, 147 GatherV2, 133 Sub, 117 Minimum, 98 Slice, 92 Maximum, 77 ConcatV2, 77 Cast, 64 Rsqrt, 60 StridedSlice, 59 Relu6, 55 Conv2D, 54 Pack, 52 Greater, 49 Shape, 46 Split, 46 Where, 45 ExpandDims, 40 Fill, 37 Tile, 33 RealDiv, 33 DepthwiseConv2dNative, 30 Range, 29 Switch, 27 Unpack, 26 Enter, 25 Squeeze, 25 ZerosLike, 23 NonMaxSuppressionV2, 14 Merge, 12 BiasAdd, 12 FusedBatchNorm, 11 TensorArrayV3, 8 NextIteration, 6 TensorArrayWriteV3, 6 TensorArraySizeV3, 6 Sqrt, 6 Exit, 6 TensorArrayGatherV3, 5 TensorArrayScatterV3, 5 TensorArrayReadV3, 3 Rank, 3 Equal, 3 Transpose, 3 Assert, 2 Exp, 2 Less, 2 LoopCond, 1 All, 1 TopKV2, 1 Size, 1 Sigmoid, 1 ResizeBilinear, 1 Placeholder
To use with tensorflow/tools/benchmark:benchmark_model try these arguments:
bazel run tensorflow/tools/benchmark:benchmark_model -- --graph=/home/ubuntu/model-optimization/frozen_inference_graph.pb --show_flops --input_layer=image_tensor --input_layer_type=uint8 --input_layer_shape=-1,-1,-1,3 --output_layer=detection_boxes,detection_scores,detection_classes,num_detections
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should copy the input layer dims, you can find in the .ascii file of your model